# Обновление фрагмента

Tags: java, android-fragment

Есть функция `refresh()` в фрагменте, которая обновляет содержимое в нем.  Каким образом можно сделать функцию статической, чтобы ее можно было бы вызвать из другого класса?

```
  public class LoftFragment extends Fragment {
        public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
        static TextView temp_indor;
        static TextView humidity_indor;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loft_layout, container, false);
            temp_indor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.temp_indor);
            temp_indor.setText(ParseData.value_temp_indor);
            humidity_indor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.humidity_indor);
            humidity_indor.setText(ParseData.value_humidity_indor);
            return view;
        }

        public static void refresh() {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Я знаю три варианта:

1. Статическая функция и обращаться к ней через `LoftFragment.refresh()` (Худший вариант, я б так делать не советовал)
2. Через интерфейс (Неплохо, но можно проще)
3. И лучший вариант обращаться через экземпляр объекта: Где то наверху объявляем `Fragment loftFragment = new LoftFragment();` а потом `loftFragment.refresh()`

Третий способ подойдет только если рефрешить надо из активити, иначе надо делать через интерфейс.